# RoR: why does this validation fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This one really has me. I have this validation in my user model:

```
validates :first_class, :presence => true, :inclusion => %w(Fighter Ranger Magician)
```

Now, I try an example create in my console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :053 > new = User.create(:first_class => 'Magician')
 => #<User id: nil, ...
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :054 > new.errors
 => {:first_class=>["can't be blank", "is not included in the list"]}
```

Why am I getting this validation error? I SERIOUSLY cannot figure that out.

(If i remove the validation, the user gets created, but first_class is nil :O)

Comment: maybe try having `attr_accessable :first_class` in your model file

Comment: oh my yes :O It was in front of me :) Please make it a question and i will vote it thanx ! The incredible thing is that i was looking at it. Guess it's one of the time that the mind stops working :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try having `attr_accessible :first_class` in your model file

You have to tell rails which attributes are writeable through mass-assignment. The `new` method takes a parameters hash, which is considered mass-assignment. The same is true with `update_attributes`.

To verify, you could just make a new instance and say `object.first_class = 'Magician'`. If this also fails, then you know `attr_accessible` is not the problem.